# Speeding up pixel recognition in java

Tags: java, awtrobot

i am writing a program that requires me to scrape data from the screen, i am doing this by going over each pixel in the screen and saving the color but this is a very expencive opration and takes along time

the folowing code is what i am using to scrape the data

```
try
{
     Robot r = new Robot();
     for( int a = 0; a < height; a++ )
     {
          for ( int b = 0; b < width; b++ )
          {
               Color p = r.getPixelColor(a, b);
               int red = p.getRed();
               int blue = p.getBlue();
               int green = p.getGreen();

               screen[a][b][0] = red;
               screen[a][b][1] = blue;
               screen[a][b][2] = green;
           }
      }
}
catch( AWTException e ) {}
```

is there any way i can improve this or are there any alternatives to using this class or method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Robot.createScreenCapture()` to create a `BufferedImage` of a specific area in a single method call.

If that doesn't work for security reasons, your second option is to modify the sources to make it render the UI in a `BufferedImage` which you can then clone to analyze it (or analyze it directly if you can prevent changes to it).

Comment: if i assign that to a variable can i just iterate through it as if it was a pixel on the screen or do i need to do it a different way

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. Do you know how to work with BufferedImage? if not, read this: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.awt.image/imagepixel.html In your case, you probably want to copy the pixels into an `int` array for faster access where each entry is the whole RGB color (instead of creating three arrays).